# PushSharp: Authentication Failed GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I know that there's a similar post of this but I still have the problem.

I'm using the PushSharp library.
When I send pushes locally it works fine. The push is received on my mobile.

But on my QA server I'm getting the "Authentication Failed" error. I tried using different Api Server Keys, including the same one I use locally but anything works. Also I tried with setting different IPs of my server, the FW IP, the public IP, the 0.0.0.0/0 IP or even leaving it empty...

Any suggestion?